# css & angular - background image loading dynamically with greyscale

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

Im going to transform picture above like this as background photo in CSS. Im using angular.My goal is to change photo path for every new item in my list. For now on styles are hardcode,  so image is constant, and everything is working.

When I try to change image by

`style="background: url({{item.photo_path}})"`

it is changing, but without `greyscale and opacity` etc.

Image: [image]

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctu88jdj/).

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do ?? https://jsfiddle.net/ctu88jdj/14/

Comment: I try to overwrite hardcoded image url in grayscale CSS class. The issue is  filters declared in class are not working, when i use inline styles to do it. Answer I expect is the way to replace background image on fly with working filters

Answer (score 1):

I did what you want to do with 
HTMl

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="ibox blog background-photo" >
    <div  ng-repeat="element in events">
        <img ng-src="{{element.path}}" class="desaturate"/>
    {{element.path}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
var modul = angular.module('app', []);

modul.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.events = [{path: 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHlKwDrqoGMi34rBHhCCzweO5GoedRt2U2iA_UBQfx1VZcKGkkPw'}];
});
```

CSS

```
img.desaturate{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: gray; filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

Working DEMO on fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ctu88jdj/17/

I hope this will help you

Comment: Your approach is quite close. The solution is:

Comment: Your approach is quite close. The solution is: put another div with `position:absolute; top:0; width: 100%;  background:url('');` under div with content with `relative position; background: transparent;` This will cause that background url can be change dynamically, and styles will be saved.

Comment: Good to hear that you got solution If my answer helped then click on right icon

Comment: Your approach is quite close. The solution is: put another div with `position:absolute; top:0; width: 100%;  background:url('');` under div with content with `relative position; background: transparent;` This will cause that background url can be change dynamically, and styles will be saved. Bug in this approach was that, styles didnt work at background image if onlu url were overwritten, or worked on all div, becouse pseudo selectors arent avilable at style attr of div